# why isn't my copy constructor called when I do a copy and swap idiom?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, copy-and-swap

In the following code, when assignment operator is used, why is the copy constructor not being called or why is there no print corresponding to it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Person {
private:
    char* name;
    int age;
public:
    Person() {
        name = nullptr;
        age = 10;
    }
    Person(const char* p_name, int p_age) {
        name = new char[strlen(p_name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, p_name);
        age = p_age;
    }

    Person(Person const& p) {
        cout << "Person copy constructor with " << p.name << endl;
        name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, p.name);
        age = p.age;
    }

    /*self assignment
    The first is the self-assignment test. This check serves two purposes: it's an easy way to prevent us from running needless code on self-assignment,
    and it protects us from subtle bugs (such as deleting the array only to try and copy it). 
    But in all other cases it merely serves to slow the program down, and act as noise in the code; self-assignment rarely occurs, so most of the time 
    this check is a waste. It would be better if the operator could work properly without it.*/
    /*
    Person& operator=(Person const& p) {
        cout << "Person copy assignment with " << p.name << endl;
        if(this != &p){
            delete[] name;
            name = nullptr;
            name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
            strcpy(name, p.name);
            age = p.age;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    */

    /*exception safety
    If in the previous approach the memory allocation fails and throws an exception then the data in name is gone*/
    /*
    Person& operator=(Person const& p) {
        cout << "Person copy assignment with " << p.name << endl;
        char* temp_name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
        strcpy(temp_name, p.name);
        delete[] name;
        name = temp_name;
        age = p.age;
        return *this;
    }
    */

    //copy and swap idiom
    /*
    . Not only that, but this choice is critical in C++11, which is discussed later.
    (On a general note, a remarkably useful guideline is as follows: if you're going to make a copy of something in a function,
    let the compiler do it in the parameter list.‡)
    */
    Person& operator=(Person p) {
        cout << "Person copy assignment with " << p.name << endl;
        swap(*this, p);
        return *this;
    }

    /*
    A swap function is a non-throwing function that swaps two objects of a class, member for member. We might be tempted to 
    use std::swap instead of providing our own, but this would be impossible; std::swap uses the copy-constructor and 
    copy-assignment operator within its implementation, and we'd ultimately be trying to define the assignment operator in terms of itself!
    */
    friend void swap(Person &a, Person &b) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.name, b.name);
        swap(a.age, b.age);
    }

    Person(Person&& other) {
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    ~Person() {
        if(name)
            cout << "Person destructor called for " << name << endl;
        delete[] name;
    }
};

int main() {
    Person p("Ryan", 28);
    Person a(p);
    a = p;
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```xml
Person copy constructor with Ryan
Person copy constructor with Ryan
Person copy assignment with Ryan
Person destructor called for Ryan
Hello World
Person destructor called for Ryan
Person destructor called for Ryan
```

Comment: What do you mean no print for it? The second line is exactly that. Where do you expect another?

Comment: Why is this closed? According to the output the copy constructor is being called just fine : )

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP expected the copy constructor message to appear after the copy assignment message.

Comment: @john Yeah I was writing that as an answer when got closed in the middle LOL

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, at least of the one mentioned. The copy constructor is not elided (as expected). In fact the Copy constructor is called before the assignment - corrosponding to the print line. (to OP: try inserting a print before the line `a = p;`)

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist you now have a chance to finish your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> why is the copy constructor not being called/there is no print corresponding to it.

Actually it's being called just fine. You can see right here in your own output:

```xml
Person copy constructor with Ryan
Person copy constructor with Ryan <--- This is it : )
Person copy assignment with Ryan
```

See here is the call site:

```
a = p;
```

and this is your assignment operator:

```
Person& operator=(Person p) {
    cout << "Person copy assignment with " << p.name << endl;
    swap(*this, p);
    return *this;
}
```

So the copy constructor is being called here for who? and when? It's being called for this parameter `p` (with the RHS of the `=` from the call site as its parameter) right before entering the body of your `operator=` code. Hence in the output you see it as the line adjacently preceding this one:

```xml
Person copy assignment with Ryan
```